# What does setting label to this 'string' here accomplish in seaborn (pandas)?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

```
sns.countplot(tweets_df['label'],label ='Count')
```

```
    id  label   tweet
0   1   0   @user when a father is dysfunctional and is s...
1   2   0   @user @user thanks for #lyft credit i can't us...
2   3   0   bihday your majesty
3   4   0   #model i love u take with u all the time in ...
4   5   0   factsguide: society now #motivation
... ... ... ...
31957   31958   0   ate @user isz that youuu?Ã°??ÂÃ°??ÂÃ°??ÂÃ°??ÂÃ°??ÂÃ°...
31958   31959   0   to see nina turner on the airwaves trying to...
31959   31960   0   listening to sad songs on a monday morning otw...
31960   31961   1   @user #sikh #temple vandalised in in #calgary,...
31961   31962   0   thank you @user for you follow
31962 rows Ã 3 columns
```

Isn't label an array?

I thought changing the value of label would change the visual label on the graph.

Comment: Your dataframe has a "label" column and your function is using a "label" param. You should clarify which "label" you're talking about at each moment.

Comment: Im talking about the 2nd param where label is set to count. I thought this was merely changing the visual label legend on the graph, but when I played around with it, the graph still said 'Label'. Maybe this is just a bug in my learning environment?

Comment: `label='foo'` sets a legend label. It sounds like you're talking about the x-axis label, which you can set with `plt.xlabel('foo')`

Comment: thats what i thought, i think tis because im working in a virtual machine as part of a lesson plan and it just doesnt change because of the format. 
https://gyazo.com/faaf7f674cba778cb2026f127d9d6566

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your virtual machine. As I said, the `label` param is for a legend. Your plot has no legend, so the `label` param is useless here. You're talking about the x-axis label, which you should set with a completely different command `plt.xlabel('foo')`.

Comment: You can set `plt.xlabel("")` to remove it.  Note that the ylabel already is automatically set to "Count" to show that the y axis indicates the count values.